# Como descobrir qual tab está ativada

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou programando em JSF utilizando Primefaces. Nisso eu estou com um formulário que possui 4 tab's e eu preciso verificar qual tab está ativada para poder chamar o meu javascript e validar os dados inseridos no momento que a pessoa clicar em próximo no componente wizard do primefaces.

Eu sei que a tab sem está ativada possui esta classe

```
ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all
```

E quando ela está ativada possui essa outra classe como complemento

```
ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight
```

Estas classes ficam dentro de li e eu coloquei um tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 em cada classe para poder usar como id, já que elas não estão pegando id não sei o porquê. Componentes primefaces tem dessas coisas.

Aí na função validar logo abaixo é onde eu valido os componentes de cada tab, eu preciso validar os componentes dependendo da tab em que eu estiver, se não, se eu estiver na tab2 vou chamar o script para validar os componentes da tab1 e isso dá erro. A minha intenção é usar alguns IF. Tipo se estivar na tab1 faça isso, tab2 faça isso.

```js
function validar(){
  
}
```

```css
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0081c2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ui-wizard-step-titles ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
  <li class="ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all  ui-state-highlight tab1">Dados Pessoais</li>
  <li class="ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all tab2">Vida Acadêmica</li>
  <li class="ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all tab3">Vida Profissional</li>
  <li class="ui-wizard-step-title ui-state-default ui-corner-all tab4">Dados Familiares</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="validar();">Próximo</button>
```

O botão de próximo aí não funciona é porque o botão que eu estou usando é o do próprio wizard, ele mesmo já chama a próxima tab. E a função que uso lá para chamar o script quando clico nele é o onnext();

```
<p:wizard nextLabel="Próximo" onnext="return onnext();"  flowListener="#{alunoBean.onFlowProcess}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu precisei fazer algo parecido, eu peguei o id da tab ativa no back end, usando o método do flowListener, por exemplo:

```html
<p:wizard nextLabel="Próximo" onnext="return onnext();"  flowListener="#{alunoBean.onFlowProcess}">
```

E no bean ficaria assim:

```
public String handleFlow(FlowEvent event) {
  String currentStepId = event.getCurrentStep();  
}
```

Para mais detalhes, você pode acessar a documentação [aqui](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf) na página 551 do PDF(versão 6.0).